# Is there any method to control parameter expansion in Bash here document?

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, shell, sqlplus

I am writing a `Bash` script which operates `Oracle` database through `sqlplus`:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

......
sqlplus / as sysdba <<'EOF'
select group#,members,bytes/1024/1024,status from v$log;
alter database add logfile group 4 ('/data/oracle/oradata/$ORACLE_SID/redo04.log') size 300M;
......
exit
```

The `$ORACLE_SID` is a bash environment variable, and I want to be substituted by its value; while `$log` in `v$log` shouldn't be expanded since it is the value used in `sqlplus` command.

Using "`<<'EOF'`" or "`<<EOF`" only expand the value or not. Is there any good method can accomplish my target?

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you should simply escape the $ in $log and $vlog, to bypass expansion.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: Yeah, you are right! It is so simple. If you are pleased, you can write the answer, then I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what exactly you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you should simply escape the `$` in `$log` and `$vlog`, to bypass expansion.